# Vertex factors for Feynman rules in QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, fourier-transform, interactions, yang-mills

I am stuck in deriving the vertex factor for the Feynman diagrams for the QCD Lagrangian. For the quantum Yang Mills theory we will have the following interacting Lagrangian.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}_{\text {int }}= & -g f^{a b c}\left(\partial_\mu A_\nu^a\right) A_\mu^b A_\nu^c-\frac{1}{4} g^2\left(f^{e a b} A_\mu^a A_\nu^b\right)\left(f^{e c d} A_\mu^c A_\nu^d\right)+g f^{a b c}\left(\partial_\mu \bar{c}^a\right) A_\mu^b c^c \\
& +g A_\mu^a \bar{\psi}_i \gamma^\mu T_{i j}^a \psi_j+i g A_\mu^a T_{i j}^a\left(\phi_i^{\star} \partial_\mu \phi_j-\phi_j \partial_\mu \phi_i^{\star}\right)+g^2 \phi_i^{\star} A_\mu^a T_{i k}^a T_{k j}^b A_\mu^b \phi_j,
\end{aligned}\tag{26.8}
$$
For the time being consider only three gluon interaction part, which is the first term. Consider the type, polarisation and momenta of the incoming gluons are $(a,\mu,k)$, $(b,\nu,p)$,$(c,\rho,q)$. Then the vertex factor is coming to be (Schwarz, pp. 510)
$$
=g f^{a b c}\left[g^{\mu \nu}(k-p)^\rho+g^{\nu \rho}(p-q)^\mu+g^{\rho \mu}(q-k)^\nu\right].\tag{26.9}
$$
In the above vertex factor, I understand the appearance of $g^{\mu\nu}$ due to the polarisations but how the $(k-p)^\rho$ type of terms are coming?

Comment: Hint: try looking at scalar QED where these also show up.

Answer (score 3):

The interaction vertex with 3-gluons is:
\begin{align*}
S_{I(3G)}=&- ig_s \eta_{\rho \nu} f^{a b c} \int d^4 x \int d^4 p_1 \int d^4 p_2 \int d^4 p_3\,p_{1 \mu} \widetilde{g}^{a \rho}(p_1)  \widetilde{g}^{b \mu}(p_2)  \widetilde{g}^{c \nu}(p_3)e^{ix_\sigma(p_1^\sigma+p_2^\sigma+p_2^\sigma)}
\\
=&- i g_s \eta_{\rho \nu} f^{a b c} (2 \pi)^4  \int d^4 p_1 \int d^4 p_2 \int d^4 p_3\,\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma+p_2^\sigma+p_3^\sigma) p_{1 \mu} \widetilde{g}^{a \rho}(p_1)  \widetilde{g}^{b \mu}(p_2)  \widetilde{g}^{c \nu}(p_3) 
\end{align*}
A brute force chain derivative gives:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\delta^3 \widetilde{g}^{a \rho}(p_1)  \widetilde{g}^{b \mu}(p_2)  \widetilde{g}^{c \nu}(p_3)}{\delta \widetilde{g}^{a' \rho'}(p'_1)  \delta \widetilde{g}^{b' \mu'}(p'_2) \delta \widetilde{g}^{c' \nu'}(p'_3)}=&\delta^a_{c'}\delta^b_{b'}\delta^c_{a'}\delta^\rho_{\nu'}\delta^\mu_{\mu'}\delta^\nu_{\rho'}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)
\\
&+\delta^a_{c'}\delta^b_{a'}\delta^c_{b'}\delta^\rho_{\nu'}\delta^\mu_{\rho'}\delta^\nu_{\mu'}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)
\\
&+\delta^a_{b'}\delta^b_{c'}\delta^c_{a'}\delta^\rho_{\mu'}\delta^\mu_{\nu'}\delta^\nu_{\rho'}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)
\\
&+\delta^a_{a'}\delta^b_{c'}\delta^c_{b'}\delta^\rho_{\rho'}\delta^\mu_{\nu'}\delta^\nu_{\mu'}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)
\\
&+\delta^a_{b'}\delta^b_{a'}\delta^c_{c'}\delta^\rho_{\mu'}\delta^\mu_{\rho'}\delta^\nu_{\nu'}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)
\\
&+\delta^a_{a'}\delta^b_{b'}\delta^c_{c'}\delta^\rho_{\rho'}\delta^\mu_{\mu'}\delta^\nu_{\nu'}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)
\end{align*}
This gives terms of the form:
\begin{equation*}
\eta_{\rho \nu}f^{a b c} \delta^a_{c'}\delta^b_{b'}\delta^c_{a'}\delta^\rho_{\nu'}\delta^\mu_{\mu'}\delta^\nu_{\rho'}\int d^4 p_1 d^4 p_2 d^4 p_3\, p_{1 \mu}\delta^{(4)}(p_1^\sigma -{p'}_3^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_2^\sigma -{p'}_2^\sigma)\delta^{(4)}(p_3^\sigma -{p'}_1^\sigma)=\eta_{\nu' \rho'} f^{c' b' a'}p'_{3 \mu'},
\end{equation*}
up to some obvious permutations. Using these ones gives the total contribution of the vertex to be:
\begin{align*}
&\eta_{\nu' \rho'} f^{c' b' a'}p'_{3 \mu'}+\eta_{\nu' \mu'}f^{c' a' b'} p'_{3 \rho'}+\eta_{\mu' \rho'}f^{b' c' a'} p'_{2 \nu'}+\eta_{\rho' \mu'}f^{a' c' b'} p'_{1 \nu'}+\eta_{\mu' \nu'}f^{b' a' c'} p'_{2 \rho'}+\eta_{\rho' \nu'}f^{a' b' c'} p'_{1 \mu'}
\\
=&g_sf^{a' b' c'}[\eta_{\mu' \nu'}(p'_3-p'_2)_{\rho'}+\eta_{\nu' \rho'}(p'_1-p'_3)_{\mu'}+\eta_{\rho' \mu'}(p'_2-p'_1)_{\nu'}]
\end{align*}
Which should be, ignoring the primes, the correct expression you gave (maybe up to some rearrangements...)

---

**EDIT**

One can ask "where does this method come from?" It follows from the hereafter observation. Take the generating functional of the theory:
\begin{align}
Z[J,\overline{\eta},\eta] =& \int \mathcal{D} g \mathcal{D} c \mathcal{D} \overline{c}\,e^{i S[g,c,\overline{c}]+i\int d^4x\,J^a_\mu g^{a,\mu}+i\int d^4x\,(\overline{\eta}{}^a c^a+\overline{c}{}^a \eta^a)}
\end{align}
Now, decompose $S$ into $S = S_\text{quad}+S_\text{int}$ where $S_\text{quad}$ contains all the quadratic terms in the fields, and $S_\text{int}$ all the interaction terms. Now pull the interaction action out of the generating functional, like this:
\begin{align}
Z[J,\overline{\eta},\eta] =& e^{iS_\text{int}\left[ \frac{-i\delta}{\delta J},\frac{i\delta}{\delta \overline{\eta}},\frac{-i\delta}{\delta \eta} \right]}\int \mathcal{D} A \mathcal{D} c \mathcal{D} \overline{c}\,e^{i S_\text{quad}[g,c,\overline{c}]+i\int d^4x\,J^a_\mu A^{a,\mu}+i\int d^4x\,(\overline{\eta}{}^a c^a+\overline{c}{}^a \eta^a)}
\\
\stackrel{!}{=}& e^{iS_\text{int}\left[ \frac{-i\delta}{\delta J},\frac{i\delta}{\delta \overline{\eta}},\frac{-i\delta}{\delta \eta} \right]}e^{\frac{i}{2}\int d^4x \int d^4y\,J^a_\mu(x) G^{ab,\mu \nu}_{\text{gluon}} (x-y) J^b_\nu(y)}e^{i\int d^4x \int d^4y\,\overline{\eta}^a(x) G^{ab}_{\text{ghost}} (x-y) \eta^b(y)}
\end{align}
Now, you can easily use Fourier transform to have:
\begin{align}
Z[\tilde{J},\tilde{\overline{\eta}},\tilde{\eta}] =& e^{iS_\text{int}\left[ \frac{-i\delta}{\delta \tilde{J}},\frac{i\delta}{\delta \tilde{\overline{\eta}}},\frac{-i\delta}{\delta \tilde{\eta}} \right]}e^{\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \int \frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\,\tilde{J}^a_\mu(p) \tilde{G}^{ab,\mu \nu}_{\text{gluon}} (p-q) \tilde{J}^b_\nu(q)}e^{i\int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \int \frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\,\tilde{\overline{\eta}}^a(p) \tilde{G}^{ab}_{\text{ghost}} (p-q) \tilde{\eta}^b(q)}
\end{align}
Then, you can express this as a Weierstrass transform (see [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ho/AQFTNotes.pdf), eq.(2.39)) as follows:
\begin{align}
Z[\tilde{J},\tilde{\overline{\eta}},\tilde{\eta}] =&\left. e^{\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \int \frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\,\frac{-i\delta}{\delta\tilde{J'}^{a}_\mu(p)} \tilde{G}^{ab,\mu \nu}_{\text{gluon}} (p-q) \frac{-i\delta}{\delta\tilde{J'}^b_\nu(q)}}e^{i\int \frac{d^4 p}{(2\pi)^4} \int \frac{d^4 q}{(2\pi)^4}\,\frac{i\delta}{\delta\tilde{\overline{\eta'}}^a(p)}\tilde{G}^{ab}_{\text{ghost}} (p-q) \frac{-i\delta}{\delta\tilde{\eta'}^b(q)}}e^{iS_\text{int}\left[ \tilde{J'},\tilde{\overline{\eta}'},\tilde{\eta'} \right]+\int d^4x (J'J+\overline{\eta}'\eta+\overline{\eta} \eta')} \right|_{J',\overline{\eta}',\eta'=0}
\end{align}
Where the primed fields are new dummy variables. For our purpose, we will make the following (schematical) expansion:
\begin{equation}
Z[\tilde{J},\tilde{\overline{\eta}},\tilde{\eta}] \sim \left. \left[ \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \int \frac{d^4q}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{-i\delta}{\delta \tilde{J'}(p)}G(p-q) \frac{-i\delta}{\delta \tilde{J'}(q)} \right]^3 iS_\text{int,3G}\left[ \tilde{J'},\tilde{\overline{\eta}'},\tilde{\eta'} \right]^2+\cdots\right|_{J',\overline{\eta}',\eta'=0}
\end{equation}
Where the ellipsis contains all the other terms. This is a "sunset" bubble, constituted by three propagators and two vertices. To isolate one vertex, it suffices to take half of the derivative with respect to the sources, take only $S_\text{int, 3G}$ and not $S_\text{int, 3G}^2$, and ignore the propagators and the integrals. So for the 3-gluons vertex, we use the operator $\propto \frac{\delta^3}{\delta \tilde{J'}{}^a_\mu (p)\delta \tilde{J'}{}^b_\nu (q) \delta \tilde{J'}{}^c_\rho (k)}$. Or stated differently, upon changing the name of the dummy variable we differentiate over:
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^{abc}_{\mu \nu \rho}(p,q,k) \propto \frac{\delta^3 S_\text{int}[\tilde{g},\tilde{c},\tilde{\overline{c}}]}{\delta \tilde{g}{}^{a,\mu} (p)\delta \tilde{g}{}^{b,\nu} (q) \delta \tilde{g}{}^{c,\rho} (k)}
\end{equation}
This is indeed the formula I used before and it is a powerful one (when the interaction action doesn't have a too large power in the fields (otherwise the calculation becomes horrible)).

---

**Note**

I have $(2\pi)^4$ factors missing in my very first equation, but these disappear in the third one because we integrate out Dirac deltas in the impulsion representation.

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain why you are taking the chain derivative and after that how you are plugging in the terms in the $S$ matrix element?

Comment: @TanmoyPati This method comes from the path integral formalism. I've noticed that you did not include the interaction terms from the Faddeev-Popov ghosts (which are necessary) in your interaction Lagrangian. Since you are talking about the S matrix, are you familiar with the path integral formalism?

Comment: I am not well efficient in path integral yet. But I have included the Faddeev Popov ghosts $\bar{c}$ and $c$

Comment: Whatever I know to calculate the amplitude in path integral, we have to couple the field with a current $J$ and variation with respect to $J(x)$, I don't know yet whether it is the only procedure. Here you are varying with respect to the gluons, So, if possible give some reference, which will be helpful for me.

Comment: @TanmoyPati I will make an edit, you can find the procedure of deriving the gluons' vertices in any good book on QFT. (sorry for the FP ghosts, I was on my phone so the screen was more narrow and I didn't see them...)